# Multiple actions in ifelse() function

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

I was looking fo the answer but I didn't find any. Is it possible to put multiple action in `ifelse()` function? Or I have to find other solution?

Example:

```
vec <- c(1,3,4,6,8,4,2,4,6,8)
ifelse(vec %% 2 == 0, "even", "odd")
[1] "odd"  "odd"  "even" "even" "even" "even" "even" "even" "even" "even"
```

Now I want print "odd" or "even" and when it's even I'd like to print even element of vector and when it's odd I'd like to print increased element of vector by 1:

```
ifelse(vec %% 2 == 0, "even"; vec, "odd"; vec+1)
```

Desired result:

```
[1] "odd"  "odd"  "even" "even" "even" "even" "even" "even" "even" "even"
> vec
 [1] 2 4 4 6 8 4 2 4 6 8
```

Comment: `ifelse(vec %% 2 == 0, paste("even", vec), paste("odd", vec + 1))`

Comment: Ah thanks, I knew that is some way :) But as I see it helps with print data, what about modyfing some variable for ex, incrementation or other calculation?

Comment: I think you mean this `vec[vec %% 2 != 0] <- vec[vec %% 2 != 0] + 1`

Comment: Yes indeed. So I can't put all of teese in one `ifelse()` statement?

Comment: You mean the printing and the modifying of the vec? I don't understand. State exactly what you expect to get

Comment: Why can't you have `ifelse(vec1 %%2 ==0, vec1, vec1 + 1)`

Comment: Let's say that I want printed "odd" and "even", and then when I print whole vector just by typing `vec` I want to see odd values increased by one. The problem is that I have `ifelse()` in `apply()` and if condition is fulfilled it should add value to the row and increment the counter by one. Question is edited.

Comment: For that you can set the names of the vector to `odd` or `even`